# How to update observableArray via success handler of an Ajax call?

Tags: ajax, arrays, knockout.js

I have tried to create an observableArray (which, using jQuery templating lists the info on the page), and what I'd like to do is on button click (though ideally on page load) is run an ajax call and update the array.

Here is what I have but it isn't working, it gives an error:

> this.propertyDetails is undefined

HTML:

```html
<button data-bind="click: addProperty">Add property</button>
```

JS:

```
var viewModel = {
propertyDetails: ko.observableArray([   
    {name: "1", type: "Unknown"},
    {name: "2", type: "Unknown"},
    {name: "3", type: "Unknown"},
    {name: "4", type: "Unknown"}
]),

addProperty: function() {
    //this.propertyDetails.push({name: "New Thing", type: "Unknown"});

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'count=10',
        url: 'http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/tomleadbetter?callback=?',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function(i,item){
                console.log(item);
                this.propertyDetails.push({name: item.d , type: item.u});
            });
        }
    }); 
}
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

It runs the ajax call on button click, but fails when trying to push each item into the array.

Don't get me wrong, I may have got this completely incorrect! But this line work on button press to insert into the array:

```
this.propertyDetails.push({name: "New Thing", type: "Unknown"});
```

So any pointers would be great.

Comment: a-ha, I needed to do this:      viewModel.propertyDetails.push({name: item.d , type: item.u});

That does it nicely :). Now then, within knockout, how do I run that on pageload?

Comment: Run what aspect of the code on pageload? Apply the bindings or run the ajax call?

Comment: I think what I need to do is get the url (which will have parameters in) and then on page load run the ajax call and that will feed by array.

Comment: I think you should read up on JavaScript and what "this" means when doing JavaScript. In JavaScript, the "this" keyword has a function scope instead of a block scope, common amongst languages as C# / Java. If you debug using Firebug, you would see what the value of "this" is in the context of your success handling function. It's not what you expect ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should work on your problem description. Fails completely isn't very specific. Does it throw an error or does it run without error, but do nothing?

My first guess is that `this.propertyDetails` doesn't resolve because `this` isn't what you think it is. You could try doing a `console.log(this.propertyDetails)` and see what happens. If it's undefined then the `this` reference is the problem and you can fix it by adding `.bind(viewModel)` to your handler function.

e.g.

```
addProperty: function() {
    //this.propertyDetails.push({name: "New Thing", type: "Unknown"});

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'count=10',
        url: 'http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/tomleadbetter?callback=?',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function(i,item){
                console.log(item);
                this.propertyDetails.push({name: item.d , type: item.u});
            }.bind(viewModel);
        }
    }); 
}
```